# MQTT not triggering ConnectionClosed

Tags: c#, mqtt

How Mqtt Manages internet disconnections ?

```
void Connection() {
  MqtClient client = new MqttClient (brokerEndPoint,brokerPort,false,null,null,MqttSslProtocols.TLSv1_2);
  client.MqttMsgPublishReceived += ReceiveFromSubScribedChannel;
  client.MqttMsgPublished += ReceivePublishAcknwldg;
  client.ConnectionClosed += OnClientdisconnected;
  client_id="client_" + UnityEngine.Random.Range (1, 111);
  client.Connet(client_id);
}
```

for me the callback ConnectionClosed is not triggering any messages . Could anyone help me in this regard?

Comment: How are you testing the ConnectionClosed callback?

Comment: By turning off my wifi

Comment: I was able to fix this by connecting the client like below  client.Connet(client_id,username,password,fals,3); where 3 is my keep alive period and i was able to receive the callback ..

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this by connecting the client like below

`client.Connet(client_id,username,password,false,3);`

where 3 is my keep alive period and I was able to receive the callback.
If Keep alive period is provided to client connection it pings the broker for every 3(keepaliveperiod) seconds and if internet disconnects I can receive a callback in my `onconnectionclosed` event